# Create individual columns from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am having a dataset extracted from a json file in the format

```
{"Y": 5, "X": [626,1,2,3]}, {"Y": 3, "X": [3]}, {"Y": 5, "X": [41847,1233]}
```

I extracted it from the json file to a pandas dataframe as:

```
X               Y  
[626,1,2,3]     5

[3]             3

[41847,1233]    5
```

How can i convert it into

```
 X1  X2  X3  X4  Y

626   1   2   3  5

3   NAN NAN NAN 3

41847 1233 NAN NAN 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` to loop through the items in `X` column and convert each list to a `Series` object, which will then give you a data frame with elements in the list arranged as columns:

```
pd.concat([df.X.apply(pd.Series).rename(columns="X{}".format), df.Y], axis=1)

#        X0      X1   X2   X3  Y
#0    626.0     1.0  2.0  3.0  5
#1      3.0     NaN  NaN  NaN  3
#2  41847.0  1233.0  NaN  NaN  5
```

---

```
df.X.apply(pd.Series)

#         0       1    2    3
#0    626.0     1.0  2.0  3.0
#1      3.0     NaN  NaN  NaN
#2  41847.0  1233.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Or `df['X'].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix('X').join(df['Y'])` perhaps?

Comment: @Zero Sure. I like the usage of `add_prefix`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Does Pandas gives me the feature of removing duplicate rows from the dataframe @Psidom?

Comment: 1. Upvote this answer 2. Search SO again if you've another separate question. 3. If not, ask again anew. Hint: Yes, and it's been answered on SO already.

Comment: @kashf34Kashf You can use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove duplicated rows.